# C# Convert Hex string to byte

Tags: c#

Little bit stuck on this, I have a var called PORTBhex holding a value in the range 0x00 to 0x3F which is written to an external device via USB. The problem I am having is getting the value into this bit of code:

```
public bool PORTBwrite()
        {
            Byte[] outputBuffer = new Byte[65];
            outputBuffer[0] = 0;
            outputBuffer[1] = 0x00; //Command tells PIC18F4550 we want to write a byte

            outputBuffer[0] = 0;
             //Must be set to 0

            outputBuffer[2] = IO.PORTBhex;
                 //Hex value 0x00 - 0x3F to write to PORTB
                 //above line gives the error cannot implicity convert string - byte
                 //IO.PORTBhex is returned from the code in second snippet

            if (writeRawReportToDevice(outputBuffer))
             {
                 return true; //command completed OK

             }else{

                 return false; //command failed .... error stuff goes here

             }
        }
```

Now the problem is the value i have is an integer that is converted to hex using:

```
 public static string ToHex(this int value)
{
    return string.Format("0x{0:X}", value);
}
```

The value starts off as an integer and is converted to hex however I cannot use the converted value as its of the wrong type I am getting Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'byte'.

Any idea what I can do to get around this please?

Thanks

EDIT:

I think I might have poorly described what I'm trying to achieve, I have an int variable holding a value in the range 0-255 which I have to convert to Hex which must be formatted to be in the range 0x00 to 0xFF and then set outputBuffer[2] to that value to send to the microcontroller.

The integer var has some maths performed on it before it needs to be converted so i cannot solely use byte vars and has to be converted to a hex byte afterwards.
Thanks

Comment: Why do you convert it to a string in the first place?

Comment: Be careful with that `ToHex`... unless you have some other way of knowing the length of each piece of data, `X2` may be preferable to `X`; i.e. output `0A` instead of `A`

Comment: Sorry  I should have mentioned that the integer that is converted to hex is based on bool vars so the input will never be anything outside of the range 0-255

Comment: oh and the data being put into outputBuffer[2] must be formatted as 0x00 to 0xFF as this is interpreted directly in a microcontroller program. Thanks

Comment: @TomPoulton: I think you are incorrectly interpreting the specification of your microcontroller. `"0x00"` is a string that represents four single bytes. You can't assign that to one single byte. Just try using the integer directly and you will see that it will work.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I will test it out and see if I can just send the integer directly. At present it works if I just give it a fixed hex value in the ranges I mentioned. As I'm using a USB library written by someone else I am not 100% sure of the workings of it, however I do know that 64 bytes are sent in one hit, could inputBuffer potentially hold a value larger than just a single byte? I was under the impression that would have been 2 bytes rather than 4 as the largest value of a single byte would be FF=255 or am i misinterpreting the meaning of 0x? Thanks Tom

Comment: @TomPoulton: In the future, address people via the @ sign followed by their name, just as I am doing it right now. Like that, they will be notified. Is it still necessary to answer that comment of yours now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solution is to change `PORTBhex` to be of type `byte` and don't use that `ToHex` method at all:

Instead of `IO.PORTBhex = ToHex(yourIntValue)` use this:

```
IO.PORTBhex = checked((byte)yourIntValue);
```

It would be even better if you could make `yourIntValue` to be of type `byte`, too.

Comment: Instead of using `checked` (which is rather slow) just do `value & 0xFF`.

Comment: @leppie: Semantically, those two options are very different. Which one to use depends on what the OP wants. I decided to use `checked`, because I think the user should be warned if he tries to use a value greater than the maximum possible value for `byte`.

Comment: Cheers Daniel, you were spot on with that answer just changed to it to Byte and used the integer value directly. Works a charm :)

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I have a decimal value which I need to convert into hex ex: `141` which I have and I want to send as `0x8D` as a byte

Answer (score 0):

```
outputBuffer[2] = Convert.ToByte(IO.PORTBhex, 16);
```

Although personally I'd probably try to avoid strings here in the first place, and just store the `byte`

Comment: I tried this but I get connot convert from int to System.IformatProvider

Comment: this was the code i tried:                                                                         int MyInt = 255;
           byte Mybyte;

           Mybyte = Convert.ToByte(MyInt, 16);